# Is there a way to find out which class instance created 'this'

Tags: public

**I(one instance of a class) want to find out say which class instantiated me? 
I have a class C that is instantiated by Class A and Class B. I want to find out which class instantiated me, so that I can access the variable from that class.

The usual way is to pass in an identifier that hey I am from class A and pass in the variable x in the constructor for the C to consume in the way appropriate for it.

**

eg:

```
public Class A
{
   public int x;

   public A()
   {
     C c = new C();
   }
}

public Class B
{
   public int x;

   public B()
   {
     C c = new C();
   }
}

public Class C
{
   public CMethod()
   {
     // I want Access int x from the class that instantiated me.

    if I know its B then B.x ...
   }
}
```

Comment: What's the language? Add the tag.

Comment: It looks like it's java.  I'm pretty sure that if you were a terrible, awful person you could accomplish this with reflection and sacrificing goats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to know without some hacking (see below). This looks like a case for an interface…

Classes A and B define HasX which has a getX() method. You can pass either class to the constructor of C which expects any class which implements HasX. Then C can call getX on either object and it doesn't need to know which type it actually is, but it will get the appropriate X value.

```
public interface HasX {
    public int getX();
}

public class A implements HasX {
    private int x;

    public A()
    {
        C c = new C(this);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}

public class B implements HasX {
    private int x;

    public B() {
        C c = new C(this);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}

public class C {
    HasX hasX;

    public C(HasX hasX) {
        this.hasX = hasX;
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        int x = hasX.getX();
    }
}
```

To answer you original question though, the object which created an object is not stored anywhere… but you can do some hacking when C is constructed for find out the class. Here is some code I once used for a Logging implementation which could detect who was the caller by looking back along the stracktrace of a Throwable. Again, this is not good practice, but you asked so… :)

From: https://github.com/slipperyseal/atomicobjects/blob/master/atomicobjects-lang/src/main/java/net/catchpole/trace/PrintTrace.java

```
public C() {
   String whoCalledMe = whereAmI(new Throwable());
}

private String whereAmI(Throwable throwable) {
    for (StackTraceElement ste : throwable.getStackTrace()) {
        String className = ste.getClassName();
        // search stack for first element not within this class
        if (!className.equals(this.getClass().getName())) {
            int dot = className.lastIndexOf('.');
            if (dot != -1) {
                className = className.substring(dot + 1);
            }
            return className + '.' + ste.getMethodName();
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

You might want to edit this to simply return the class name, or even do a Class.forName() to resolve the actual class.

If you want the actual objects, and there is only ever 1 of each class, you could out the objects in a Map keyed on classname. But gee what a mess around :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know that interface is the key here. I was wondering if there is some way using maybe reflections to find out. I wanted to see the various options that we might have or lack there of.

I bumped into this issue with some legacy code which was not coded to interface clearly and I wanted to be able to dynamically update a certain counter based on who initiated the class.

Comment: There is a hacky way you can find out, by adding some code to the constructor of C. I have edited my answer to include it. :)

Comment: Well, this code gives you the class, not the actual object.